# Question related to direction of current

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance

I believe we have all been told that current flows from high potential to low potential by convention but in reality current is flow of electrons which flow from low to high. Now as in reality current flows from low to high then potential should increase across a resistor or any other electrical device which means that th potential energy is being increased rather than getting decreased, this contradicts a resistor which creates an energy loss where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dale has addressed your misconception about the direction of current. There is a further misconception in your question, which is that negatively charged particles moving from low to high potential increase in potential energy. In fact, the opposite is true. The change in potential energy $\Delta U$ for a charge $q$ that moves through potential difference $\Delta v$ is
\begin{align}
\Delta U = q \Delta V.
\end{align}
When $q$ is negative — take for example $q = - e$ for an electron — then
\begin{align}
\Delta U = - e \Delta V.
\end{align}
The change in potential energy will be negative if the potential difference $\Delta V$ is positive.

Comment: +1 excellent point! I completely overlooked that

Answer (score 3):

> in reality current is flow of electrons which flow from low to high

This is not correct. Current is defined so that it points in the opposite direction of the electron flow. So current in a resistor still flows from high potential to low potential.

It is wrong to equate current with the motion of electrons. First, in many materials, such as electrolytes in batteries or in the human body, at least some of the charge carriers are positive. Second, even in metallic wires current is not equal to the velocity of the charge carriers but to the charge of the charge carrier times the velocity. For negative charge carriers it is therefore opposite the flow of electrons.

Comment: Not to mention holes as charge carriers in solids.